# Serializing User model

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following code that should return me all the Users that are registered in my site, but for some reason it just returned me the last signed user, I need all the users in my JSON.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from profiles.serializers import ProfileSerializer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view


class ProfilesAPI(APIView):
serializer = ProfileSerializer

def get(self, request, format=None):
    users = User.objects.all()
    response = self.serializer(users, many=True)
    for j in range(0,len(response.data)):
     dictionary = response.data[j]
     myresponse = ""


    for i, (val, v) in enumerate(dictionary.items()):
         myresponse = [{"text":v} for v in dictionary.values()]
         print(myresponse)


    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'messages': myresponse}), content_type='application/json')
```

and throws me this, even I have more than one user registered.

[My JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnxCi.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is where your problem lies:

```
dictionary = response.data[j]
```

You declare the dictionary and at the same time, you the existing value with the latest value in the loop. By the time the loop exits, The dictionary would contain only one result (The last one in the loop)

you should declare it outside the loop and then call `dict.update` something like this:

```
dictionary = {}

for j in range(0,len(response.data)):
    dictionary.update(response.data[j])
```

That solves your problem.

But there's no point generating a this new dictionary. You can just iterate once on `response.data` if you need to customize the response.

since `response.data` is a list of users you can do this instead

```
dictionary = {'messages': []}

for user in response.data:
    dictionary['messages'].append({'text': user['id']})
    dictionary['messages'].append({'text': user['username']})
```

Also since you're using django rest framework and the `APIView` you don't need `json.dumps`

django framework has a `Response` class that takes care of that and it also sets the appropriate headers.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
```

and then change your return statement to:

```
return Response(dictionary)
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your response. It will be something like this? 

 def get(self, request, format=None):
  users = User.objects.all()
  response = self.serializer(users, many=True)
  dictionary = {}

  for j in range(0,len(response.data)):
   dictionary.update(response.data[j])
   myresponse = ""

  for i, (val, v) in enumerate(dictionary.items()):
    myresponse = [{"text":v} for v in dictionary.values()]
    print(myresponse)

Comment: Ok I update it like the following: 

class ProfilesAPI(APIView):
 serializer = ProfileSerializer

 def get(self, request, format=None):
  users = User.objects.all()
  response = self.serializer(users, many=True)
  dictionary = {'messages': []}

  for user in response.data:
   dictionary[messages].append({'text': user.id})
   dictionary[messages].append({'text': user.username})


  return Response(dictionary)


But it returns me an error 'name 'messages' is not defined'.

Comment: You should have quotes around the messages i.e `dictionary['messages']`. i've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful. 

Now it throws me this error: Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'id' 

It doesn't work, for username or id.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. It's an Ordered dictionary not an object I've updated my answer